# C code that I dont understand

Tags: c

When reading [Enlightenment's](http://www.enlightenment.org/) code, I found some things about C I don't understand. I'll paste the lines and explain why its not clear to me.

```
Eina_Bool (*hide)(void *data, Evas_Object *o);
void (*del)(void *data, Evas_Object *o);
```

On this ones, what do that pointer values between parentheses means just after return value?
Also, notice that the first parameters of both functions is `void *data`. Does that mean you can pass a pointer to any type of data to the function?

```
EAPI Ecore_X_Window elm_win_xwindow_get(const Evas_Object *obj);
```

Almost all functions on the API starts with `EAPI`. What does that mean? Is it a kind of namespaces? Where can I find some info about that?

Also notice how they use one of it's libraries: [Elementary](http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/elementary/group__Start.html).

```
EAPI_MAIN int elm_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // CODE
}
ELM_MAIN()
```

Instead of using a main function, you use that elm_main with again those uppercase flags: `EAPI_MAIN`.
And just after the function there is that weird `ELM_MAIN()` without semicolons.

I'll appreciate if you guys explain me a bit about all this that seemed strange the very first time I saw them.

Note: All of the examples I pasted came from [elm_win.h](http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/browser/trunk/elementary/src/lib/elm_win.h) Elementary header.

Comment: For the very first question, they are function pointer. EAPI is an empty define, possibly just for the purpose of annotating the code. ELM_MAIN() is define to be the main() function that calls elm_init and call elm_main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines that you show here are declarations of function pointer variables.

A line of the form:

```
int (*foo)(int x)
```

for example declares a variable called foo that can hold (the address of) a function that takes one integer argument (`x`) and returns an integer. If you declare a function like this:

```
int twice( int x )
{
    return x*2;
}
```

you could assign (the address of) that function to the variable foo.

```
foo = twice;
```

and then you could call the function `twice` through the pointer:

```
int result = foo( 3 );
```

(`result` would now contain 6)

The usual reason to so something like this is that you know you want to call some function at a certain point in the code, but exactly what function depends on other code. If you had functions called `process_A` and `process_B` you might assign one of them to a function variable:

```
int (*process)(int x);
process = using_b ? process_B : process_A;
... more code ...
result = process( some_value );
```

here the result is set to the value calculated either by `process_A` or by `process_B`, depending on which one was assigned to `process`

You could use a conditional at the point of call, of course, but selecting the function and storing it (or rather its address) in a variable leads to more efficient and (more importantly) clearer code.

As for the `EAPI` symbol ... I don't know Enlightenment, but I would expect that that is just a macro #defined in a header. It probably changes the calling convention or exports symbols depending on the build options.

Answer (score 0):

Those first two statements are function pointer definitions. I.e. pointer variables that take the address of a function.

A type of `void *` can accept any valid pointer value or a null pointer. It's mandatory to somehow keep track of what's the actual type a `void *` pointer points to, to properly typecast the `void *` to the actual type bahind it. The common use for this is providing means to pass arbitrary user typed data to callback functions. And that's what the two function pointers are for.

This statement

```
Eina_Bool (*hide)(void *data, Evas_Object *o);
```

means: *hide* is a pointer to a function that accepts as parameters a `void *`, a `Evas_Object *` and returns a `Eina_Bool`.

Note that this substantially different to the subtely different statement

```
Eina_Bool* reveal(void *data, Evas_Object *o);
```

Which would be a function named `reveal` returning a `Eina_Bool*`.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this source](http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/efx/Efx_8h_source.html) defining `EAPI`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# ifdef EFL_EFX_BUILD
#  ifdef DLL_EXPORT
#   define EAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#  else /* ifdef DLL_EXPORT */
#   define EAPI
#  endif /* ! DLL_EXPORT */
# else /* ifdef EFL_BUILD */
#  define EAPI __declspec(dllimport)
# endif /* ! EFL_BUILD */
#else /* ifdef _WIN32 */
# ifdef __GNUC__
#  if __GNUC__ >= 4
#   define EAPI __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#  else /* if __GNUC__ >= 4 */
#   define EAPI
#  endif /* if __GNUC__ >= 4 */
# else /* ifdef __GNUC__ */
#  define EAPI
# endif /* ifdef __GNUC__ */
#endif /* ! _WIN32 */
```

These are all compiler flags.

Now, regarding your `hide` and `del` question; These are not functions, but function *pointers*. That is, if you dereference `del`, you'll get a function of this type:

```
void del_impl(void *data, Evas_Object *o);
```

This allows for runtime selection of which function to call, based on online data.